# Using C#, how do I add triggers and indexes to an Oracle database table?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, indexing, triggers

How would one go about creating triggers to an Oracle table in C#? The Oracle version I am working with is 11g. I can run the Oracle command that will create the table, in C#. But I am unable to create triggers and add indexes, since they require a semicolon, and when I run oracle commands in C# with semicolons in the command string, I get an error.

Running Oracle command strings in C#, that add triggers and indexes.

```
var createCommand = "CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (TESTSTRING VARCHAR(20))";

var alterTable = "ALTER TABLE TESTTABLE  ADD( CONSTRAINT TESTID PRIMARY KEY(id) );";

var combined = createCommand + alterTable;

    using (var connection = Database.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var command = Database.GetCommand(combined , connection, CommandType.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

There should be a table called TESTTABLE showing up in the database.

Comment: Sorry, I had the parenthesis in code, but it got left out of my post. Also, unfortunately, if I add a ; to the createCommand, it will not work and give me an error that there is an invalid character.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are using standard `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` by default. AFAIK these do not allow ';' as a separator for multiple commands, instead you need to include a transaction. ';' is database specific, so you should be able to get around the issue by specifying the connection and command types (eg replace 'var connection' with '`OracleConnection` connection'). You will need to reference `Oracle.ManagedDataAcess` which you can get from Nuget. Please note I have not tested this for Oracle.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm going to try that tomorrow when I am back at work! This is awesome, hopefully will resolve my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having got to my office myself, I decided to test Oracle (I know ";" works at least with SQL Server.  Unfortunately the ODP.Net implementation does not allow this.  So you have two possibilities: either wrap your statements in a batch marked with `BEGIN` and `END;`, with the individual commands prefaced with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '.. your command here ..';`, or you can re-use the Command, by altering the `CommandText` and re-executing.

Incidentally your SQL had another problem as well; you were trying to create a primary key on a column that wasn't included in your create table!

I show below an example using both techniques.  Please note that I am constrained to use a specific schema for my tables (hence the extra "feosi.").  Also note that in the alternative example there are no semi-colons: including them leads to an invalid character exception.

```
var createCommand = "execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE FEOSI.TESTTABLE (ID int, TESTSTRING VARCHAR(20))';";

var alterTable = "execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE FEOSI.TESTTABLE  ADD( CONSTRAINT TESTID PRIMARY KEY(ID) )';";

var combined = "BEGIN " + createCommand + alterTable + "END;";

var altCreateCommand = "CREATE TABLE FEOSI.TESTTABLE2 (ID int, TESTSTRING VARCHAR(20))";
var altAlterTable = "ALTER TABLE FEOSI.TESTTABLE2  ADD( CONSTRAINT TESTID2 PRIMARY KEY(ID) )";

using (OracleConnection oracleConn = new OracleConnection(myOracleConnStr))
{
    oracleConn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand oracleCmd = new OracleCommand(combined, oracleConn))
    {
        //Do everything in one batch
        oracleCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        oracleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //alternative re-use Command
        oracleCmd.CommandText = altCreateCommand;
        oracleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        oracleCmd.CommandText = altAlterTable;
        oracleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome.